# Spring Boot 2 Actuator Null Pointer Exception [ InMemoryAuditEventRepository bean is null ]

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have spring-boot project with following dependencies

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.rakugakibox.spring.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-access-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.audit4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>audit4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
        <version>${micrometer.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.audit4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>audit4j-db</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.audit4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>audit4j-spring</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ical4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>ical4j</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.20</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasypt-spring31</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty-transport-native-epoll</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.24.Final</version>
        <classifier>linux-x86_64</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jmockit</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmockit</artifactId>
        <version>${jmockit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>${junit-jupiter-api.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${junit-jupiter-engine.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${junit-vintage-engine.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
        <version>${junit-platform-launcher.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-runner</artifactId>
        <version>${junit-platform-runner.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
        <version>${junit-platform-surefire-provider.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
        <version>${junit-jupiter-params.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Rest Api of this module gives following error randomly. It first appears when unauthorized request comes.

```
2018-Sep-11 16:55:45.887 ERROR [,http-nio-8090-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.audit.listener.AuditListener.onAuditEvent(AuditListener.java:48) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.audit.listener.AbstractAuditListener.onApplicationEvent(AbstractAuditListener.java:33) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.audit.listener.AbstractAuditListener.onApplicationEvent(AbstractAuditListener.java:28) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:400) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:354) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.security.AbstractAuthorizationAuditListener.publish(AbstractAuthorizationAuditListener.java:50) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.security.AuthorizationAuditListener.onAuthorizationFailureEvent(AuthorizationAuditListener.java:67) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.security.AuthorizationAuditListener.onApplicationEvent(AuthorizationAuditListener.java:47) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.security.AuthorizationAuditListener.onApplicationEvent(AuthorizationAuditListener.java:33) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:400) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:354) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.publishEvent(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:504) ~[spring-security-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:236) ~[spring-security-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:124) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at net.rakugakibox.spring.boot.logback.access.tomcat.LogbackAccessTomcatValve.invoke(LogbackAccessTomcatValve.java:91) [logback-access-spring-boot-starter-2.7.1.jar!/:2.7.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_181]
2018-Sep-11 16:55:50.393 INFO  [,pool-12-thread-1] c.a.m.a.AbstractDistributedNonLockingA
```

Further looking at spring code reveals error appers here .

```
public class AuditListener extends AbstractAuditListener {

    private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(AuditListener.class);

    private final AuditEventRepository auditEventRepository;

    public AuditListener(AuditEventRepository auditEventRepository) {
        this.auditEventRepository = auditEventRepository;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAuditEvent(AuditEvent event) {
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug(event);
        }
        this.auditEventRepository.add(event);
    }

}
```

It seems like some how `auditEventRepository` is null. I think it should be initialized with `InMemoryAuditEventRepository`.

What might causing this issue ? where should I investigate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing piece not configuring the `AbstractAuditListener`

```
@Component
public class AuditApplicationEventListener extends AbstractAuditListener {

private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuditApplicationEventListener.class);

@Override
protected void onAuditEvent(AuditEvent event) {
    log.info("On audit event: timestamp: {}, principal: {}, type: {}, data: {}",
            event.getTimestamp(),
            event.getPrincipal(),
            event.getType(),
            event.getData()
    );
}
```

}

This tutorial was very useful http://blog.codeleak.pl/2017/03/spring-boot-and-security-events-with-actuator.html . Above code taken from this tutorial.